# What does a tick like in math?

Tags: riddle

[image: very purty rose]

You have to think logically on this riddle; you may search anything you want.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason the photo was added to the question?

Comment: yes it used to be my old photo for my profile and i really like it and thx for being curious i was actually waiting for someone to notice that so thank u very much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this it not so much a puzzle as it is a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint made it all too easy:

> arithmetic.

Comment: and you are right don't tell anyone   ssssssshhhhhhhhhh

Comment: +10000000000000